# configure-Step of ATLAS installation fails on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, lapack, blas, atlas

I'd like to install ATLAS v.3.10.1 on OSX Mavericks following the intructions of [the ATLAS website.](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node6.html)

Unfortunately the step calling ../congire [flags] fails with the error message:

```
cat: ..//CONFIG/src/Makefile: No such file or directory
cp: ..//CONFIG/src/atlcomp.txt: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `xconfig'.  Stop.
```

I've read about a similar (but not exactly the same) issue due to tar command of OSX, but I have no solution seen for it. In particular I'm confused if this really is the problem. Does anybody have an idea how I could proceed?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? I'm working on it myself.

Comment: No, unfortunately no further proceedings...